# When executing a .sql script in Java, can I get the number of rows affected?

Tags: java, mysql, ibatis

I am using JDBC to connect to a remote database, and then ibatis ScriptRunner to execute a query.

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url3); 
ScriptRunner runner = new ScriptRunner(con);
runner.setSendFullScript(true);
runner.setStopOnError(true);
runner.runScript(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Script/Test.sql")));
```

This code executes the script for me, and 2 rows are affected in the database. Is there a way to get and print the number of rows effected, similar to what you would see in Messages when executing the script in SQL Server Management Studio?

EDIT: HERE IS THE SCRIPT I AM TRYING TO RUN

```
USE Dashboard;
DECLARE @userName1 varchar(MAX);
SET @userName1 = 'jrambo';
DECLARE @ExternalUserID1 int;
SET @ExternalUserID1 = (SELECT ExternalUserID FROM ExternalUsers WHERE username = @userName1);

DELETE FROM DBO.INTERESTPREFS WHERE InterestID in (SELECT InterestID FROM DBO.INTERESTS WHERE externaluserid IN (@ExternalUserID1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with JDBC executeBatch() method instead of using ScriptRunner :

```
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
String line = null;
 BufferedReader in = 
   new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Script/Test.sql")));

// Read your sql file line by line 
while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
  // and add SQL statements in the batch.
  stmt.addBatch(line); 
}
// int[] to hold returned values
int[] count = stmt.executeBatch();

//commit statements
conn.commit();
```

executeBatch will return you an integer array described in Java doc :

> The elements in the array returned by the method executeBatch may be
>   one of the following:
>
> A number greater than or equal to zero -- indicates that the command was processed successfully and is an update count giving the
>   number of rows in the database that were affected by the command's
>   execution
>
> A value of SUCCESS_NO_INFO -- indicates that the command was processed successfully but that the number of rows affected is unknown

Comment: I tried using the example you posted to execute my script. My test completes without errors, but the script does not run (I checked the database to verify). It does run successfully when using ScriptRunner. Are there certain limitations with a script when running it using executeBatch

Comment: yes, i think you should have basically an sql instruction by line or something like that. is that the case in your script ?

Comment: My script is very basic. I have added it to the original question. This script should delete 2 lines from the database. It works when using ScriptRunner, but not with executeBatch. I'm not sure why it wouldn't work with executeBatch, since the test completes with no errors.

Comment: what is 'stmt' here?

Comment: stmt is the Object containing the SQL Statement